# Convert floating point numbers to user defined output using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to convert floating point numbers (columns) from a text file to the user defined output using **awk**,  e-01 -> $\exp 10^{-01}$

Test input:

```
1.2e-01  
1.8e-02  
1.12e-03  
1.222e+04 
1.23e+05  
441.2e+05 
221.2e+06
```

Expect results

```
1.2$\exp 10^{-01}$
1.8$\exp 10^{-02}$
1.12$\exp 10^{-03}$
1.222$\exp 10^{+04}$
1.23$\exp 10^{+05}$
441.2$\exp 10^{+05}$
221.2$\exp 10^{+06}$
```

I have used the following command "**awk '{printf "%.4e\n", $1}'**", which does not solve this problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this simple `sed` substitution with a capturing group and a back-reference:

```sh
sed -E 's/e([+-][0-9]+)/$\\exp 10^{\1}$/' file
```

```
1.2$\exp 10^{-01}$
1.8$\exp 10^{-02}$
1.12$\exp 10^{-03}$
1.222$\exp 10^{+04}$
1.23$\exp 10^{+05}$
441.2$\exp 10^{+05}$
221.2$\exp 10^{+06}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/ +$/,"");sub(/e/,"$\\exp ");sub(/[-+]/,"10^{&");$0=$0"}$"} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  sub(/ +$/,"")         ##Substituting space at last of line with NULL in each line.
  sub(/e/,"$\\exp ")    ##Substituting e with $\\exp in current line.
  sub(/[-+]/,"10^{&")   ##Substituting either - or + with 10^{ with matched - or +
  $0=$0"}$"             ##Appending }$ at current line.
}
1                       ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would treat input as text and do two subsequent replacements, namely:

```
awk '{$0=gensub("e", "$\\\\exp 10^", 1); $0=gensub("(-|+)([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+", "{\\1\\2}$", 1); print}' file.txt
```

Let `file.txt` be:

```
1.2e-01  
1.8e-02  
1.12e-03  
1.222e+04 
1.23e+05  
441.2e+05 
221.2e+06
```

then output is:

```
1.2$\exp 10^{-01}$
1.8$\exp 10^{-02}$
1.12$\exp 10^{-03}$
1.222$\exp 10^{+04}$
1.23$\exp 10^{+05}$
441.2$\exp 10^{+05}$
221.2$\exp 10^{+06}$
```

Explanation: I alter whole line (`$0`), firstly I replace `e` with `$\exp 10^` (`\` needs to be escaped), secondly I search for sign (`-` or `+`) followed by (one or more digits) followed by one or more space or tab, which I replace with `{signdigits}$`. Finally I `print` altered line.